# run MasterEmulator.dll without admin rights

Tags: c#, python, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a Nordic USB Dongle and I want to create a simple C# application to scan and connect with other BLE devices.

But i faced first problem when create new instance of MasterEmulator class.

```
MasterEmulator masterEmulator = new MasterEmulator();
```

The program run well with admin rights but without admin it had exception :

> Thrown: "Could not load file or assembly 'IronPython.Modules, Version=2.7.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7f709c5b713576e1' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified." (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)    Exception Message = "Could not load file or assembly 'IronPython.Modules, Version=2.7.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7f709c5b713576e1' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.", Exception Type = "System.IO.FileNotFoundException"

My customer required us to run on the account non-admin,that is problem, anyone have experience with that ? Please help

Thanks,

Comment: Tthe error message says the file is not found, not that you don't have access rights or privileges.  Does the file actually exist?

Comment: I think the file is not found because the program can not access to read that file, cdarke

Comment: I think it more likely that the file or assembly is in a directory that is not within the search path.  Not sure how you get from "not found" to a permissions failure, they are two different error conditions.

Comment: Try to ask at Nordic's Q&A site: https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/questions/ (Usually you get a very fast response.)

Comment: I would like to thanks for your reponses